# How to select all the values in drop-down one by one using protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I got the count of the values inside the drop down and trying to click on each option one by one and verify something but I couldn't click on options.

```
let button = $('[href* ='something']');
let dropdown = element(by.id('someid'));
let options = dropdown.all(by.tagname('option'));

button.click();

options.then(function (items) {

    console.log(items.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        items[i].gettext().then(function (text: any) {
            items[i].click();
        });
    }
});
```

Its showing me error as gettext() is not a function and I tried getattribute('value') also still no use,Can someone help on this please

Comment: you made a typo. It should be `getText()`, rather than `gettext()`

Answer (score 2):

```
let button = $('[href* ='something']');
let dropdown = element(by.id('someid'));
let options = dropdown.all(by.tagname('option'));

button.click();
 for (let i = 0; i < options.count(); i++) {
        options.get(i).getText().then(function (text: any) {
            options.get(i).click();
        });
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Since `items` is array of elements, you have to use `get(//element position in the array)` to access the particular element in the array.

refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: @DublinDev Thanks for the inputs. Will update the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer Madan..Now I'm getting error for 'get(i)' as "property 'get' doesn't exists on type any[]|Elementfinder[]

Comment: Same error madan "Failed: options.get(...).gettext is not a function"

Comment: @manaswini the problem with case. `gettext()` should be `getText()`. Could you try with the updated answer

Comment: @manaswini Do mark the answer correct so that it helps others who face the same problem

Comment: @manaswini Do mark the answer correct so that it helps others who face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when the option is going get generated in the DOM.
In the for loop try

```
browser.driver.findElements(element(by.css('#someid option')).then(elms => {
          return elms[i].click();
}
```

Comment: Rohan actually I'm able to click by drop down options one by one but I'm trying to verify if the selected option in the drop down is matching to the one it is displaying on screen